# Массовое скачивание файлов (изображений) с стороннего сервера

Tags: php, алгоритм, файлы, ftp

Есть очень интересная задача, найти самый оптимальный вариант скачивания файлов (JPG,PNG) с стороннего сервера при том, что файлов может быть очень много 3000-5000 тыс и каждая может весить пару **MB**  т.е в итоге получаем несколько **GB** файлов. Первый и самый важный вопрос, есть ли такая практическая  возможность, скачать все файлы одним запросом? например используя метод `copy()` в цикле.

Приведу практический пример, есть много онлайн площадок которые принимают `xml` фиды, а точнее автовыгрузка объявлений, как у авито, ирр или циан. Все такие площадки получают инофрмацию через `xml` в том числе и изображения. Вот простой кусок кода:

```
<Images>
    <Image url="http://img.test.ru/8F7B-4A4F3A0F2BA1.jpg" />
    <Image url="http://img.test.ru/8F7B-4A4F3A0F2XA3.jpg" />
</Images>
```

получается что данные площадки просто обходят по всем ссылкам  `url` и скачивают их к себе... но каким методом они это делают?, что у них не возникают проблемы(timeout. обрыв связи). Я протестировал у себя, при обходе `xml` файла и скачивание всего 1000 картинок у меня ушло около 2-3 минуты и после `timeout`.... но как они скачивают файлы по одному и не получают таймаут? Уверен, что у них на сервере не установлен безлимит на работу скрипта.

Единственное логическое решение приходит в голову, обходить и скачивать файлы по очереди т.е через крон каждую минуту читать файл и скачивать по 100-200 файлов(как пример). Возможно есть более оптимальное решение?, вот чувствую, "истина где-то рядом" буду рад любым подсказкам :)

Comment: сам спросил - сам ответил. удаляйте ссылку из массива после скачивания, и крутите его, пока пустой не станет. ну или не наберется несколько неудачных попыток скачивания для файла (в случае каких-то обрывов) и просто удаляйте при 404 и т.п.

Comment: @teran, да, просто возможно есть другой способ,  может кто то имеет практику в такой ситуации, или вряд ли будет более оптимальный метод?

Comment: если у вас постоянно поступают новые входные данные, то один подход, если просто есть набор ссылок - то просто обработайте. мультикурл какой нить в помощь. Но если вы хотите разом махнуть 2 гига с хоста и это не какой нить яндекс, а обычный сайт, не положите его, делайте паузы.

Comment: @teran ,думаю так и сделаю, если конечно не найду другого решения )) Спасибо за помощь.